# Keep getting 500 "Internal error" in requests with an access token

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, android

I'm trying to fetch some data from the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)
I have a valid `access_token` and registered key but I keep getting internal error as a result.
Here is the request URL:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?site=stackoverflow&access_token=Vy*iWEzkfPKHAzx7PEtJcA%2529%2529&filter=default&order=desc&sort=reputation&key=YKCpxEolLytlJiKBUCxUJg((
```

And the response:

```
{"error_id":500,"error_message":"this error has been logged","error_name":"internal_error"}
```

What am I doing wrong/missing?

PS: I'm working on and an Android app and doing request with retrofit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are sending a malformed access token.
Your example, `Vy*iWEzkfPKHAzx7PEtJcA%2529%2529` is not of the proper form and exhibits classic URI encoding corruption.

Valid tokens all seem to be 24 characters that end in `))`.  And `)` is often encoded as `%29` by browsers depending on how you get it and/or cut and paste.
`')' === decodeURIComponent ('%29')`

Additionally, `%25` is the URI encoding of `%`, so your token was *double* URI encoded. (That's two times too many. ;)   )

---

When I send the same request, with a validly formatted token (which I have since deauthorized):
          [/2.2/me?access_token=Vza4EEmVimmN4l3O9qZ87Q)) ...](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?site=stackoverflow&access_token=Vza4EEmVimmN4l3O9qZ87Q))&key=U4DMV*8nvpm3EOpvf69Rxw(()
I get a valid result.

When I double URI-encode the token:
          [/2.2/me?site=access_token=Vza4EEmVimmN4l3O9qZ87Q%2529%2529 ...](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?site=stackoverflow&access_token=Vza4EEmVimmN4l3O9qZ87Q%2529%2529&key=U4DMV*8nvpm3EOpvf69Rxw(()
I get the same 500 error that you got.

---

---

Note:  The links above show the proper full format. Obviously, they won't work for you since I deauth'd the token (to protect my account's virginity).
You can go to [the doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me), fetch your own token, and plug it into the above links and it will work.

---

---

PS:  At this moment, your base token (`Vy*iWEzkfPKHAzx7PEtJcA))`) appears to still be valid. When I fetch the link:
          [/2.2/me?site=stackoverflow&access_token=Vy*iWEzkfPKHAzx7PEtJcA))](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?site=stackoverflow&access_token=Vy*iWEzkfPKHAzx7PEtJcA))&key=YKCpxEolLytlJiKBUCxUJg(()

I get a valid but empty result:

```
{"items":[],"has_more":false,"quota_max":10000,"quota_remaining":9998}
```

which suggests that there might be some security against token hijacking. :)